# How can I get current text from TextArea in Gradio

Tags: python, gradio

```
import gradio as gr
input1 = gr.TextArea(label="Text (100 words max)", value=example,
                                                             elem_id=f"input{i}")
```

I made a Text Area, and wanna get current text value from TextArea.

`input1.value` just returns default value that I assigned (In my case, `example`).

How can I get current value of TextArea?

Comment: can you show more code of your app, when do you want to get current value of TextArea?

Answer (score 0):

If you click a button you can pass the value as an input. For example

```
import gradio as gr
input1 = gr.TextArea(label="Text (100 words max)", value=example,
                                                             elem_id=f"input{i}")
btn = gr.Button(value="Submit")
btn.click(combine, inputs=[input1])

def combine(input1):
    print(input1)
```